# Syntax error in Android service

Tags: java, android, syntax

I use this code for connection to my service, but when I put this line

```
this.bindService(service, conn, flags);
```

I receive error message: `syntax error on token "}", { expected after this token ... (1)`

here is all code in my class:

```
package com.flaxa.fixx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void butonRunOnlyClickHandler(View target) {

        Intent activity = new Intent(this, com.flax.trainer.RunOnly.class);
        startActivity(activity);                
    }

    public void butonChallengeClickHandler(View target) {


    }

    public void butonProgramClickHandler(View target) {



    }

    public void butonCalculatorClickHandler(View target) {


    }


    ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        this.bindService(new Intent("") , conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }; 

}
```

Can some one help my with bindService function, where I'm wrong??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is this line here:

```
this.bindService(new Intent("...") , conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

You're placing this statement inside your `ServiceConnection` declaration, but not inside
a method.  Assuming you're using the `ServiceConnection` from an `Activity`, you should move
this statement to your `onCreate` or `onResume`.

Comment: thanks Erich Douglass

I this line this.bindService(new Intent("...") , conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

on onCreate  on my activity


Thanks again

Comment: No problem!  If the answer was helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkbox to the left.

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks like you are trying to invoke method outside of any method. So it's indeed not valid you'll have to move it into the body of some method in our case one line up.